# Arrange multiple divs in CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, css, ms-access

Currently I have these divs using `MDB`

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 8em;">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="rounded-rectangle-svs card current-proj">
                    <h5 class="text-default"><b>Project 1</b></h5>
                    <div class="row" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <h1 class="text-default"><b>86%</b></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rounded-rectangle-svs card current-proj">
                    <h5 class="text-primary"><b>Project 2</b></h5>
                    <div class="row" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <h1 class="text-primary"><b>86%</b></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rounded-rectangle-svs card current-proj">
                    <h5 class="text-secondary"><b>Project 3</b></h5>
                    <div class="row" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <h1 class="text-secondary"><b>86%</b></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="rounded-rectangle-svs card current-proj">
                    <h5 class="text-success"><b>Project 4</b></h5>
                    <div class="row" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <h1 class="text-success"><b>86%</b></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rounded-rectangle-svs card current-proj">
                    <h5 class="text-danger"><b>Project 5</b></h5>
                    <div class="row" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <h1 class="text-danger"><b>86%</b></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rounded-rectangle-svs card current-proj">
                    <h5 class="text-warning"><b>Project 6</b></h5>
                    <div class="row" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <h1 class="text-warning"><b>86%</b></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

and the output of these divs is like this

[image]

As you can see the 2 different div with the class name of `col-md-6` is inside the `row` div.

for each `col-md-6` contains 3 different projects.

What I'm trying to do, is it possbile to arrange these divs of projects without using col-md-6? with just `JavaScript`? with the arrangement like that too?

Because those project will be coming from my database it's a bad idea to use `col-md-6` for this situation that's why I'm trying to do the automatic arrangement of divs with two(2) columns like that even if I loaded multiple divs. It will rearrange just like that

Comment: You can try and use CSS grid to define your layout instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: You can change the width value of class in js

Comment: _“Because those project will be coming from my database it's a bad idea to use col-md-6 for this situation”_ - why? Don’t state stuff like this as if it was an absolute fact, explain what the actual problem is. Is it possible that you actually meant “I don’t know how to handle that” instead of “bad idea”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Bootstraps card layout [card-deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-decks).
You can fill a single div with x amount of cards. The width of each card can be declared in CSS by `flex-basis`.

This way there's no need for extra columns to make it responsive. Also no need to create a mapping when using CSS-grid (which is also a valid solution). No need for JavaScript solutions.

Below I've extended the card-deck layout with `two-col` class.
Similarly you can extend to three-col or four-col and so on.

**SCSS**

```
.card-deck {
    .card {
        flex-basis: 100%; // mobile first
    }

    /*@media (min-width: 768px)*/
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
        &.two-col {
            .card {
                flex-basis: calc(50% - #{$grid-gutter-width}); // -30px
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/voaz4ex2/)**