# How to Render Bootstrap 4 Cards dynamically using PHP while-loop with proper Layout

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

For my project I want to make a online shop, in which I add products, edit them or delete them. **But the problem I have isn't about functionality, it is about layout of the Bootstrap 4 cards**. For the main design and front-end I am using **Bootstrap 4**. For my back-end code I use **PHP**. The site is fully function. I add products in the code through PHP Dynamically. So the problem comes from the design part, in that case the product (card) part.

Let me explain.

The products that I add are shown in bootstrap 4 cards. When I add a product, It's showing like this.
This is looking all good, for now.[image]

When I add more products, the layout changes like this, which is incorrect.[image]

I want my  3 products (cards) to align right in the same row. The cards should also be the same, like the card in the first picture. The next product (card 4) should go in the next row and etc. Like this:[image]

I also used this design in some way, but for the functionality to work (with PHP) **I can only use one card** and then add, edit or remove products (cards). **And this is the problem**. I don't know how to fix the Bootstrap code, that will then automatically align cards in the correct way, without having the design in the code for bootstrap to call on.

This is the code from my index.php. You can see it has only one card.

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

            <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                            <img src="<?php echo $row['url'] ?>" class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
                            </img>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 class="card-title lead"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h6>
                                <p class="divider-text">
                                    <span class="bg-white lead text-muted">Description</span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="card-text lead text-muted"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></p>
                                <p class="divider-text">
                                    <span class="bg-white lead text-muted">Or skip and favorite & buy</span>
                                </p>

                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <?php
                                        $query1 = "SELECT id FROM favorite_decorations WHERE id_users = ? AND id_decorations = ?";
                                        $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($query1);
                                        $stmt1->execute([$_SESSION['user_id'], $row['id']]);
                                        $result1 = $stmt1->fetch();
                                        if (!isset($result1['id'])) {
                                        ?>
                                            <button type="button" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><a href="favorites_add.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">To favorites</a></button>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <button type="button" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><a href="favorites_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Remove from favorites</a></button>
                                        <?php }; ?>

                                        <?php
                                        $query2 = "SELECT id FROM basket WHERE id_users = ? AND id_decorations = ?";
                                        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
                                        $stmt2->execute([$_SESSION['user_id'], $row['id']]);
                                        $result2 = $stmt2->fetch();
                                        if (!isset($result2['id'])) {
                                        ?>
                                            <button type="button" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><a href="basket_add.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">To basket</a></button>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <button type="button" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><a href="basket_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Remove from basket</a></button>
                                        <?php }; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="badge badge-primary"><strong><?php echo $row['price'] ?>€</strong></div>
                                </div>

                                <?php if (is_admin()) { //If user is admin show edit/add/delete
                                ?>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="decorations_edit.php?id_decorations=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" role="button">Edit</a>
                                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" href="decorations_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" role="button">Delete</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }; // End of if
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php }; ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the code and [the link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/album/) for that Bootstrap template, which I used.

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef"
              dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its pretty vague but try putting `<div class="row">` outside your php `while` and change all `col-md-4` to `col-4` as in bs4 this gets auto adjusted

Comment: @elpidaguy Thank you. It worked :)

Comment: Better solution would be to use [Bootstrap card-deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks). In terms of responsiveness you can tackle that by using `flex-basis` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621609/arrange-multiple-divs-in-css-js/58623480#58623480). With `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` you can choose how the layout responds to gaps. Using the grid in a Bootstrap card-layout is imho counter-intuitive. [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/voaz4ex2/)